# Firebase Quota - FirebaseAuth Current User

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, quota

Does the method call to `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` count against any quota? Or is this locally maintained?

We are using the flutter plugin and can not determine if this call can be done without increasing any quotas:

`await auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is nothing more than accessing local state. No call is made for this whatsoever, so it can never hit any quota issues.

In general **determining** the current user does not hit any quota'd services that I'm aware of. It's only acts like signing in, verifying passwords/OTPs, etc, that are affected by quota.

Comment: Thanks! We were wondering why it is an async call? At some point it probably is executing a query against firebase backend to get latest user info, right? But if I understand you correctly those 'current user' calls have no price tag on it, right?

Comment: Getting the `currentUser` is no longer an async call, though it used to be in previous versions of the Flutter library (until a few months ago). Listening for auth state also doesn't have a price tag, as the process is managed by the SDKs. There are of course limits on all services, to protect agains abuse and attacks, but for such background processes they are typically much higher.